# What is this miniture coke can in my PC

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure

So I open the case of my PC and dusted out the dust bugs . I look and there are coke bottle component sticking up from the board and some are puffed and look fried or damaged.

My PC runs just fine but was running hot and so I was dusting the dust bugs out and noticed this.

What are these coke bottle components? How could these be damaged and my PC still work fine?

This part:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS8J3.png

Comment: Those are capacitors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor

Comment: When I've heard of swollen capacitors, discussions involved permanently damaged equipment.

Comment: Bad capacitors. We use to see them all the time on Mother boards. Newer boards are built better it seems. A pc normally gets very sluggish and crashes as those are going bad. You can replace them. Find a local shop or order some. I use ebay. Get the same voltage and microfarad. A trick I use after getting them out is heat the tiny holes and use a toothpick to re-open the holes for the new capacitor to slide in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are electrolytic capacitors.

I am not an electrical engineer but they basically store electricity and make it available to other parts of the motherboard, essentially "smoothing out" an electrical flow.  I could be horribly wrong about that.

They are damaged typically through getting too hot.

There was the [capacitor plague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague) which affected a lot of motherboards from the 2000's.  Any such hardware affected by the plague at this time is likely too old to be very useful or worth saving

However, plague or no plague, any electrolyic capacitor has a limited life, which is shortened by too much heat.

In my experience with Dell GX280's and similar systems of that era, damaged capacitors will cause things like unexplained freezes or slowdowns, and if they occur in the power supply (which seemed to be common), the power supply will fail and the system will not turn on.  Symptoms were more or less random.  Some systems with this issue did not display any problems.

It's possible to replace them, as you can buy capacitors, desolder the old ones, and resolder the new ones, but if the reason they failed was due to your system too hot on the inside, you need to address that issue otherwise it will happen again.  If some of the liquid has leaked on other motherboard components you may have a permanently damaged motherboard.